# Identify elvish writing from imgur?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

I was forwarded this picture; I have no idea what it says. If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

[image: Tengwar transcription]

LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMwuO.png

Comment: @Valorum http://imgur.com/D9g1zFX  Not sure that helps any.  :(

Answer (score 3):

Just opened it in the proper link and was able to read it; seems to be an advertisement for a ring shop:

"image. my preciouss iss ready to pop the quesstion! Bilbo, Gandalf, Gollum, or another Lord of the Rings character in a jewelry shop, ring shopping, of course."

Comment: "Jewelry" shop, I'd imagine.

Comment: Thank you! That's obviously what it meant. Since they're using Tengwar to transliterate English writing, it's quite non-canonical; apparently they used the letter Ungwe as a J.  Thanks again :)

Comment: That makes way more sense than mine. Ngwalme-as-y threw me for a loop. Also I was convinced the last word was "curse."

Comment: @AdeleC Yeah, that Ngwalme-thing is pretty random. Also, some Tehtar are superimposed, and words ending with a vowel have the Tehta appended to the beginning of the following word -- just the marks of a third-rate elvish transcription. *sigh*